Refresh load to another livewire component
I have a todolist app with livewire, i have a component named index for the list and import the other component named create.
When I create a task, I dispatch a event to refresh the index view, but when the livewire refresh send me to other component that are in the project named tasks.
This is a video that explain the problem: https://streamable.com/y69pyw
The this is the code of the button
I think the problem is the refresh and not the event because I added a button to refresh in the index view:
<button wire:click="$refresh">Click</button>
When i click the result is the same livewire call the tasks component and dont refresh the index component.
<button wire:click="$refresh">Click</button>

This is the index component view that call the create component:
<div class="m-2">
        <livewire:tasks.create @stored="$refresh"/>

        <div class="flex gap-2 mt-2">
            <div class="w-full">
                @forelse($tasks['realizadas'] as $task)
                    <div wire:key="{{ $task->id }}" class="border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-md mb-2">
                        <div class="bg-green-300 rounded-t-md p-2">
                            <p>{{ $task->date->translatedFormat('g:i A j \d\e F \d\e\l Y') }}
                                <b>({{ $task->date->diffForHumans() }})</b></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="p-2">
                            <p class="font-medium">{{ $task->name }}</p>

                            <div class="flex justify-end gap-2">
                                <button type="button" wire:click="indexComments({{ $task->id }})"
                                        class="bg-blue-600 text-white rounded-md py-2 px-3">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" wire:click="edit({{ $task->id }})"
                                        class="bg-yellow-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3" title="Editar">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" wire:click="delete({{ $task->id }})"
                                        class="bg-red-600 text-white rounded-md py-2 px-3" title="Eliminar">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @empty
                    <div
                        class="bg-green-300 border border-green-500 text-green-800 font-medium rounded-md p-4 text-center">
                        No tiene tareas realizadas
                    </div>
                @endforelse
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

The index component:
class Index extends Component
{
    public array $tasks = [];

    public function render()
    {
        $tasks = auth()->user()->tasks()->get();

        $this->tasks['realizadas'] = $tasks->where('status', 'Realizada');
        $this->tasks['pendientes'] = $tasks->where('status', 'Pendiente');
        $this->tasks['imprevistas'] = $tasks->where('status', 'Imprevisto');

        return view('livewire.tasks.index');
    }
}

The create component:
class Create extends Component
{
use LivewireAlert;

#[Validate(['required', 'string', 'max:255'])]
public string $name = '';

#[Validate(['required', 'date'])]
public string $date = '';

#[Validate(['required', 'string', 'max:255'])]
public string $status = '';

public function store(): void
{
    $this->validate();

    $task = auth()->user()->tasks()->create($this->pull());
    $this->dispatch('stored');

    $this->alert('success', "Tarea $task->name añadida");
}

}
The create view:
<div>
    <form wire:submit="store" class="border border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2">
        <h3 class="text-xl text-center">Crear Tarea</h3>

        <div class="flex gap-3">
            <div class="flex-1">
                <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="name" id="name"
                       class="w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md" autocomplete="on" required autofocus>
                @error('name') <span class="text-red-500 font-medium">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="flex-1">
                <label for="date">Fecha</label>
                <input type="datetime-local" wire:model="date" id="date"
                       class="w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md" required>
                @error('date') <span class="text-red-500 font-medium">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="flex-1">
                <label for="status">Estado</label>
                <select wire:model="status" id="status"
                        class="w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md" required>
                    <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                    <option value="Realizada" class="bg-green-500">Realizada</option>
                    <option value="Pendiente" class="bg-red-500">Pendiente</option>
                    <option value="Imprevisto" class="bg-yellow-500">Imprevisto</option>
                </select>
                @error('status') <span class="text-red-500 font-medium">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="flex-none">
                <button type="submit" class="bg-black text-white rounded-md mt-6 p-2">Añadir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

Thanks

The situation is not clear.
In the published code the index view has no reference to the create component, you need to explain how these components are related. You also need to post the relevant code of the index class and the create view. Also where is the stored event managed?

@TUPKAP I am sorry, I edit the question with the import of create in the index, de create view and the index component

I add a video that explains better the problem

Everything works for me. What happens if you put something like <div> {{ now() }} </div> before <livewire:tasks.created...... in the index component? Does the date update?
